# Do we need [tdd] and [unit-testing]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

Do we need [tdd](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tdd) *and* [unit-testing](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unit-testing)? I understand that they're not synonymous in the real world. One can unit test without testing first, but do we require this fine grain distinction between the two?

In the context of a code review, what does [tdd](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tdd) bring to the table that [unit-testing](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unit-testing) doesn't?

Comment: I don't think we do, but I can't put my finger on why.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes I'm feeling the same way. I was having a hard time articulating myself, so I put it out here for discussion.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[tdd](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tdd) is an indication of how OP's code was written - unit tests first. By itself alongside a language tag, it doesn't bring anything to the table IMO.

[unit-testing](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unit-testing) on the other hand, tells us that OP has unit tests, at least as part of the reviewable code - regardless of whether the code was written with TDD or not.

Since the code is already written, working and tested, whether it was done TDD, OOP and DRY is irrelevant, especially if the unit tests aren't included in the OP.

Bottom line...

- a post tagged with [tdd](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tdd) without unit tests has an irrelevant tag
- a post tagged with unit tests without a [unit-testing](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unit-testing) tag is missing a relevant tag
- a post tagged [unit-testing](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unit-testing) contains reviewable unit tests
- a post tagged [tdd](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tdd)[unit-testing](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unit-testing) is a tautology

Therefore, [tdd](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tdd) should be made a synonym of [unit-testing](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unit-testing), so as to avoid questions with both tags.

Comment: I've suggested the synonym. It needs votes. http://codereview.stackexchange.com/tags/unit-testing/synonyms